# Beginning with May but not for questioning

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verbs

The speaker says she is glad to have a new counselor and looks for his support and help in the days which lie ahead. At the end she says: "May there be many of them." [The Crown]
Why did not she say "There may be many of them"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"May" followed by the base form of a verb is used to express a wish, especially in a formal speech. May he live a long time (I hope that he lives a long time); may you have many children (I hope that you have many children).

> may
>
> modal verb (WISH)
>
> formal used to introduce a wish or a hope:
>
> May you have a long and fruitful marriage.

[May (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/may)